# Vbscript find .apk and import outlook

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I wrote a script which can find the .apk and import aoutomaticly in outlook.

But i have a problem. i can set 4 path folder. And the script look path folders and find the apk.

But when this script can find an .apk folders, the program finish.

This script doesn't look another path.

```
On Error Resume Next
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objnet = CreateObject("wscript.network")
    Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\Belgelerim\mail")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\Belgelerim\mailbox")
     For Each objFile in objFolder
         If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "pst" Then
            olkApp.Session.AddStore objFile.Path
     End If
Next
MsgBox "Done"
```

For example, this script find the path .apk folder

```
(Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\"))
```

And doesn't look another paths.

How to solve this problem.

Thanks for any helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do **never** use `On Error Resume Next` to control the program flow. This is stupid. *Check* for error predictable conditions instead of letting them fail.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objnet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 

paths = Array( _
  "C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\", _
  "C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook", _
  "C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\Belgelerim\mail", _
  "C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook", _
  "C:\Documents and Settings\" & objnet.UserName & "\Belgelerim\mailbox" _
)

For Each path In paths
   If objFSO.FolderExists(path) Then
       For Each objFile in objFSO.GetFolder(path).Files
           If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "pst" Then
                olkApp.Session.AddStore objFile.Path
           End If
       Next
   End If
Next

MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: +1 for leading your answer with admonition about `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: @PaulStock: Hah, I had to look up "admonition". Speaking English for quite some time now but still expanding my vocabulary. :)

Comment: @Hünkar Whoops, sorry. Stupid copy/paste error on my end. :-( Works now.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for helping :) But this script has an error line 15

Comment: @Hünkar \*sigh\* Not my day today, it seems. *Now* it should work.